# Where are sudo incidents logged?

Tags: logs, sudo

When someone is not in the sudoers group and try to use sudo, get an error message like this one:

`yzT is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.`

I'm trying to figure out in which log this information is logged, for check who tried to run a command with sudo for example, but can't find it.

The first Google search says `/var/log/syslog` but I don't see any information related to sudo there.

Comment: It's logged remotely: http://xkcd.com/838/

Comment: [Breaking news](https://www.sudosatirical.com/articles/police-standoff-outside-house-of-man-not-in-sudoers-file/)...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

On redhat based linux systems like centos or fedora it is in:

```
  /var/log/secure
```

and for debian based systems like ubuntu it is in:

```
  /var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: But how can I know it on my own without googling it?

Comment: Easy! Read the source code.

Comment: cat /var/log/auth.log | grep '3 incorrect password attempts'

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, it is in `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: Notices should also be emailed to root by default, though that is configurable.

Answer (score 3):

in Fedora it is in /var/log/audit/audit.log

Comment: it depends to the /etc/sudoers file, you should search for this record: Default    logfile = /var/log/file_name

Answer (score 3):

On Arch linux (and I assume other distros with systemd), sudo events are logged to the systemd journal and can be accessed with the `journalctl` command.

Use `journalctl -e` to see the recent logs, which will include a handful of messages for each successful or unsuccessful `sudo` call from various sources including `sudo` itself and the kernel.

Just the recent kernel audit messages can be seen with `journalctl -ke`. Look for the messages containing `kernel: audit: [...] exe="/usr/bin/sudo" [...]`